# How to add letter or text inside check box in Material Ui?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to make check boxes like the given image,I mean circular check boxes having any text inside.
Thanks in advance.
[Click here for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvmOE.png)

Comment: No image attached 

Comment: now see the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MUI [Avatar](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-avatar/)

```
const [isSelected , setIsSelected] = useState(false)
    


<Avatar sx={{ bgcolor: `${isSelected?'#1a73e8':'grey'}` }} onClick={() => setIsSelected(!isSelected)}>M</Avatar>
```

**EDIT**
For dynamic :

use array of object :

```
const [weekdays , setWeekDays] = useState([{
    day:'S',
    select:false
},
{
    day:'M',
    select:false
},
{
    day:'T',
    select:false
},
{
    day:'W',
    select:false
},
{
    day:'T',
    select:false
},
{
    day:'F',
    select:false
},
{
    day:'S',
    select:false
}])




 <Stack direction="row" spacing={2}>
      {weekdays.map((day, i) => (
        <Avatar
          sx={{
            bgcolor: `${day.select ? "#1a73e8" : "grey"}`,
            height: "25px",
            color: "white",
            width: "25px",
            fontSize: "12px"
          }}
          onClick={() => handleSelect(day , i)}
          alt="Remy Sharp"
        >
          {day.day}
        </Avatar>
      ))}
    </Stack>





const handleSelct = (ob, ind) => {
    const newArr = weekdays.map((obj, i) => {
      if (i === ind) {
        return { ...obj, select: !obj.select };
      }
      return obj;
    });

    setWeekdays(newArr);
  };
```

Comment: Instead of having bgcolor as static, it should be dynamic based on the selection. It will be blue if that day is selected.

Comment: have a state if it is selected then change based on it ...

Comment: yes you can use onClick to change bgColor

Comment: ok I got it,Thnx

Comment: Now the problem is:Check this link->          https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-bird-7rlr1g?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: @Noob_Mern_Dev Can you check my EDIT.

Comment: yes but plz define handleSelect()

Comment: @Noob_Mern_Dev Kindly check it. https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-water-56ybc2?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: Thnx @Dazil.It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In your case a will prefer using IconButton and useState to handle that

```
const [alarmcheck,setAlarmCheck]=useState(false)
const [cartcheck,setCartCheck]=useState(false)
<IconButton color="secondary" aria-label="alarm" sx={alarmcheck&& 
{backgroundColor:red}} onClick={ (prev)=>setsetAlarmCheck(!prev)}>
<AlarmIcon />
</IconButton>
<IconButton color="primary" aria-label="add to shopping cart" onClick={ 
(prev)=>setsetCartCheck(!prev)}  sx={cartcheck&&{backgroundColor:green}}>
<AddShoppingCartIcon />
</IconButton>
```

Give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Resolved a similar issue like this by rendering the text content as a span and passing props to a styled-component based on the active index.

I was using MUI but could not figure out an approach to add text (similar to issue that you are facing). So instead I tried this approach.

**NOTE: I am not using MUI. The only additional thing is that I am using styled-components. if you are using `emotion/styled`, that should be fine**

Following is my implementation.Maybe this might help

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const weekdaysLabel = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];

const PayoutWeekDaysStyled = styled.span<any>`
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
border-radius: 30px;
font-size: 16px;
margin: 1rem;
text-align: center;
line-height: 50px;
color: ${(props: any) => (props.isActive ? '#fff' : '#000')};
background-color: ${(props: any) => (props.isActive ? '#0094CD' : '#f4f5f7')};
&:hover {
    background-color: ${(props: any) =>
      props.isActive ? '#0094CD' : '#f4f5f7'};
    cursor: pointer;
    color: ${(props: any) => (props.isActive ? '#fff' : '#000')};
}
`;

export default function App() {
  const [weekdays, setWeekdays] = React.useState([]);
  const handleClick = (item) => {
    if (weekdays.includes(item)) {
      const updatedWeekdays = weekdays.filter((day) => day !== item);
      setWeekdays(updatedWeekdays);
    } else {
      setWeekdays([...weekdays, item]);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div style={{ display: 'flex', gap: '1rem' }}>
      {weekdaysLabel.map((item, index) => (
        <PayoutWeekDaysStyled
          key={index}
          isActive={weekdays.includes(item)}
          onClick={() => {
            handleClick(item);
          }}
        >
          {item}
        </PayoutWeekDaysStyled>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```